# Are there any good commentaries on Yerushalmi?

Tags: product-recommendation, commentaries, talmud-yerushalmi, tractate-shekalim

There is no Rashi on Yerushalmi (Shekalim specifically), and (I find that) the Gemara doesn't really explain itself as well as Bavli.

What are good free (hebrewbooks.org) running commentaries on Shekalim (like, say, the Pesher Davar)?

Comment: What's wrong with the Korban Haeida ,and the Pnei Moshe?

Comment: Are you asking about commentaries to Shekalim or all of Yerushalmi? @sam Who said anything was wrong with them?

Comment: @sam no Pnei Moshe on Shekalim, and Korban KaEida isn't as complete

Comment: @DoubleAA Either (preferably on Shekalim).

Comment: @ShmuelBrin What does that mean? Would an answer recommending the Pnei Moshe be no good? What about one that recommends a Perush only to masechet Nazir? Horyot? Demai?

Comment: Go to Hebrewbooks.org and put שקלים as the title. I've heard nice things about R' Kanievsky's volume. I also see a commentary by R' Shmuel Hilman (Rav Herzog's father-in-law). R' Shimon Friedman's massive שדה צופים includes a volume on שקלים, and his other volumes cite some very eclectic sources.

Comment: Since Shekalim is printed in the Bavli, and is part of the daf-yomi cycle, you can also listen to audio shiurim which are available from many sources online. yutorah.org has a daf yomi series on Shekalim. dafyomi.co.il has other non-audio resources on the daf, including some that go into some depth.

Comment: @Ephraim you won't find R' Kanievsky's seforim like that :) You have to search for Yerushalmi and look at the title through mouse-over.

Comment: @DoubleAA fixed. There is no Pnei Moshe on Shekalim (at least in the [Vilna print](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=5&daf=2&format=pdf))

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/vol%201%20zelcer.pdf

Answer (score 6):

This website provides a pretty decent Hebrew commentary on most of the Yerushalmi:
http://www.yedidnefesh.com/yerushalmi/yerushalmi.htm

This is a website which is a great resource for Yerushalmi and has many different commentaries, manuscripts, and essays. I have not gone through all of it, but do recommend Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky's commentary, which is hosted on HebrewBooks. 
http://www.yerushalmionline.org/   (click on the left pane "Seforim on Yerushalmi" to get the list)

Here is a very good commentary to Yerushalmi. This may be what you are looking for, and so far they only have Shekalim and Rosh Hashana. http://www.talmudyerushalmi.org/download-page/

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of [הירושלמי כפשוטו](http://www.massorti.com/IMG/pdf/liberman_yerushalmikepshuto.pdf) the commentary of Rabbi Shaul Lieberman zt"l though it is only on 3 mesechtot

Comment: I thought it was on Brachot too.